# Declaring a static interface field in Kotlin

Tags: interface, kotlin

Is it possible to write the equivalent of Java

```
interface Foo {
    public static final INSTANCE = new Foo {};
}
```

in Kotlin?

If `Foo` were a class, I could use:

```
class Foo {
    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val INSTANCE = object : Foo() {}
    }
}
```

but with an interface it gives an error:

> JvmField cannot be applied to a property defined in companion object of interface

`@JvmStatic` doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm curious, what's the purpose of using `interface` here? Wouldn't `object` make more sense?

Comment: @Michael In real code I have multiple possible implementations depending on OS and the initializer picks the correct one.

Comment: @Michael `Object` would make a singleton Class. Not applicable to an interface.

Comment: @Clinkz The point was that `Foo` _is_ meant to be a singleton. That is why the field `INSTANCE` exists.

Comment: @1blustone Obviously. The emphasis is on `Class` in that statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Kotlin 1.3 on you can do:

```
interface Foo {
    companion object {
        @JvmField val INSTANCE = object : Foo {}
    }
}
```

And call it from Java as `Foo.INSTANCE`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

```
interface Foo {

    fun bar()

    companion object {
        val INSTANCE = object : Foo { // There are no () An interface cannot be instantiated.
            override fun bar() {
                //Do something
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your activity, simply calling `Foo.INSTANCE` returns an instance to `Foo`.

Comment: Is it visible as `Foo.INSTANCE` from Java or only from Kotlin? That's the point of the question.

Comment: Yes, if you want to access the Kotlin interface through Java, instead of `Foo.INSTANCE`, use `Foo.Companion.getINSTANCE();`

I don't think there's a way to access it from Java without using Companion. Unless, you opt for `object` like @Michael suggested. I don't see any other way. :-/